# Wrapping a Table onto a new page with SelectPDF

Tags: c#, html-to-pdf, selectpdf

I'm using *SelectPDF*'s HTML to PDF converter to generate a PDF based on an HTML document containing a wide table of data.  I'd like this table to *wrap* onto a second page (or Nth) page if needed, but instead SelectPDF squeezes the table into the space available on the page size I've selected.

Comment: We gave up on SelectPDF to accomplish this.  It actually killed the PDF feature we were working on as it just wasn't high enough priority.  If we attempt it again we thought of using an RDL-based solution, as we have legacy code that does that and works.  Or we will look for some other product.